# PHP form fills with ones after submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I am stumped....

I have created a PHP form to gather some user information and email it to the site owner, after the form is submitted, the fields auto complete with a '1' I am assuming this means the field was true and submitted.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to hide or remove the 1 after the form is submitted? I just want the form to be blank after submission. Here is the code, Sorry for the poor formatting and eye bleeding wall of code.

Thank you in advance for any help!

PHP Code

```
    $errName = "";
    $errcatBreed = "";
    $errEmail = "";
    $errMessage = "";
    $result = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $catBreed = $_POST['catBreed'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'PearTreeHill Contact Form';
    $to = 'test@domain.com';
    $subject = "New furbaby enquiry from $name";

    $body ="From: $name\n Cat Breed: $catBreed\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if cat breed has been entered
    if (!$_POST['catBreed']) {
        $errcatBreed = 'Please enter either Ragdoll or British ShortHair';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    // RECAPTCHA
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
  {
        $secret = 'Private Key';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success)
        {
            $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
        }
        else
        {
            $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        }
   }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errcatBreed && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again.</div>';
    }
}
    }
```

HTML Code

```
<!-- contact form -->
<section id="contactUs" class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="w3-tangerine">Contact Us</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- start of entry form -->
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
        <!-- name entry -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['name'])); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- cat breed selection -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="catBreed" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cat Breed</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="catBreed" name="catBreed" placeholder="'Ragdoll' or 'British ShortHair'" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['catBreed'])); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errcatBreed</p>";?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- email address entry -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['email'])); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Body of message -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Please enter any other information"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['message']));?></textarea>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- reCAPTCHA -->
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Public Key" data-callback="recaptcha_callback"></div>
            <!-- send button -->
            <input disabled="disabled" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-danger">
            <label for="submit" class="col-sm-8 control-label">Please allow up to 48 hours for a response!</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- entry alert -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <?php echo $result; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['email'])); ?>
```

Here you display the result of `isset()` (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

You should do :

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST['email']) ) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>
```

And this for each field :-)

Answer (score 0):

change

echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['name']));

to

echo  htmlspecialchars ($_POST['name'])

I mean remove isset();